# Motivation for the selection of basis function of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have seen two motivations of decomposing an $L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)$ function into a Fourier series with basis functions $e^{2\pi inx}$ with $n$ being integers. The first one is the intuitive frequency representation of a signal; the second one is that the trigonometrical functions are eigenfunctions of the Laplacian, so it can help to solve PDE. I am satisfied by those explanations.

However, in Folland's *Real Analysis, Modern Techniques and Their Applications*, it gives another motivation as follows

[image]

I feel a little "unmotivated". Surely, having functions in the form $f(y+x)=\phi(x)f(y)$ can be good. But why is it deterministic for people to consider them as the building blocks? Is there any theorem in Fourier analysis that particularly uses this fact? Sorry for being a vague question, but basically, I feel it is somehow unnatural.

Comment: I would suggest that you need to look at it from the point of view of locally compact abelian groups.  The deeper theory of harmonic analysis kind of kicks off there.  Katznelson has a book on the topic which is pretty readable.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you for the comment. I was thinking in that direction but since I don't have any experience of abstract harmonic analysis I cannot claim much. Is it possibly because on a group, one only has one simple structure so the above construction is the best you can expect? Is it the correct way of thinking?

Comment: I am far from an expert in the area---I took one course in harmonic analysis in grad school, which means that I know enough to be dangerous, but not much more.  I also am a lot weaker in algebra than in analysis.  But my general impression is that your description is basically correct---in a LCA group, the only real thing that you can do is translate sets around (i.e. have the group act on itself).  This plays nice with the natural Haar measure that lives there, so it seems (to my nonexpert eye) like a good place to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be an abelian topological group. Just as we look at the dual space $X^*$ when we want to know about a vector space (a Banach space, for example) $X$, it is a natural idea that the "dual group" $G^*$ might give some useful information about $G$, and this is indeed the case. More concretely, we will consider the complex homomorphisms (usually called the **characters**) on $G$, which are continuous functions $\phi:G\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfying
$$\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)\phi(y)\qquad(x,y\in G). $$
In our case, $G=\mathbb{R}^n$ with addition (in particular, it is abelian), and the characters are precisely given by
$$\phi_t(x)=e^{it\cdot x} $$
for some $t\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

There is (at least) one more motivation to consider the characters. Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group. Then $G$ admits a unique Haar measure, and there arises a natural Banach space $L^1(G)=L^1(G,m)$. In fact, $L^1(G)$ is an abelian Banach algebra whose multiplication is given by the convolution. Then it is well known that every complex homomorphism on $L^1(G)$, that is, every function $h:L^1(G)\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $h(f*g)=h(f)h(g)$ is given by
$$h_{\phi}(f)=\int_Gf(x)\phi(-x)dx\qquad(\phi\in G^*). $$
So again, characters enter naturally. We say that $h$ is the **Fourier transform** of $f$ at $\phi$ and write $\widehat{f}(\phi)=h_{\phi}(f)$. Note that this coincides with the usual definition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if we identify $\mathbb{R^n}$ and its dual group by $t \longleftrightarrow \phi_t$.